# Libreoffice Writer (soffice.bin) uses too much memory

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

As the title clearly describes, the process of **Libreoffice Writer** - `soffice.bin` - uses too much memory `(1.22GiB)` despite that there is **only one document** which is open & contains **13 pages**. The size of the document is `78.7 KB`.

Seems like a memory leak. Are there anyone who face this issue? If so, any workarounds are appreciated.

Here is the proof of this issue:

[image: proof]

ps. My OS is Using 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

The memory that is listed in your table is very likely the virtual memory of the `soffice.bin`.

If you run `top`, you can see the virtual memory use (VIRT) and the resident set size (RSS) of system processes. The resident set size is the non-swapped physical memory used by each process, minus a small amount of overhead. So it will give you a decent idea of actual memory usage.

VIRT or VSZ (Virtual Set Size) is the memory size assigned to a process during the initial execution. The Virtual Set Size memory is simply a number of how much memory a process has available for its execution.

If you don't have `top` installed, you can run:

```
ps ax -o rss,vsize,command|sort -nr|head -n 10
```

this will give you the 10 most memory hungry processes. The first column printed is RSS and the second column is VIRT. If `soffice.bin` is in the list, it's VIRT should match what is in your table.

References:
- http://www.unixlore.net/articles/quick-easy-way-monitor-process-memory-usage.html
- https://serverfault.com/q/48582
- https://linuxconfig.org/ps-output-difference-between-vsz-vs-rss-memory-usage
- `man ps`